# How to concatenate column values in oracle based on other column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data in table like:

| CSF | ID | seqNum | Data | rs_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14176159 | 1 | ABC | 0x000055.0001882a.017c |
| 1 | 14176160 | 2 | DEF | 0x000055.0001882c.0010 |
| 1 | 14176161 | 3 | GHI | 0x000055.0001882d.00ac |
| 1 | 14176162 | 4 | JKL | 0x000055.0001882d.0164 |
| 0 | 14176163 | 5 | MNO | 0x000055.0001882f.001c |
| 0 | 14176163 | 1 | ABC | 0x000055.0001882f.00d4 |
| 1 | 14176164 | 1 | ABC | 0x000055.00018830.0144 |
| 1 | 14176165 | 2 | DEF | 0x000055.00018831.0010 |
| 1 | 14176166 | 3 | GHI | 0x000055.00018832.00e4 |
| 1 | 14176166 | 4 | JKL | 0x000055.00018832.019c |
| 0 | 14176167 | 5 | MNO | 0x000055.00018834.001c |

I want to execute select in a way to obtain the result as:

| CSF | ID | seqNum | Data | rs_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14176159 | 5 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO | 0x000055.0001882f.001c |
| 0 | 14176163 | 1 | ABC | 0x000055.0001882f.00d4 |
| 0 | 14176164 | 5 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO | 0x000055.00018834.001c |

So the logic should work like:

1. whenever CSF encountered is 1, we need to append data column until CSF is 0.
2. In the result, the ID should be of the record where CSF was first encountered as 1.
3. In the result, the SeqNum and rs_id should be of the record where CSF is 0.

So in short, CSF 1  indicates that data column is appended in next record and 0 indicates that the data column is not further split in to records and is an independent record.

Comment: Include the table data in the question as text

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT MIN(last_csf)    AS csf,
       MIN(first_id)    AS id,
       MIN(last_seqnum) AS seqnum,
       LISTAGG(data) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seqnum) AS data,
       MIN(last_rs_id)  AS rs_id
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY id, seqnum
  MEASURES
    LAST(csf)      AS last_csf, 
    FIRST(id)      AS first_id,
    LAST(seqNum)   AS last_seqnum,
    LAST(rs_id)    AS last_rs_id,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (one_csf* zero_csf)
  DEFINE
    one_csf  AS csf = 1,
    zero_csf AS csf = 0
)
GROUP BY mno
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (csf, id, seqNum, data, rs_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 'ABC', '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, 2, 'DEF', '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3, 3, 'GHI', '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 4, 'JKL', '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 5, 5, 'MNO', '05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 5, 1, 'ABC', '06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 6, 1, 'ABC', '07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 7, 2, 'DEF', '08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 8, 3, 'GHI', '09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 8, 4, 'JKL', '10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 9, 5, 'MNO', '11' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CSF | ID | SEQNUM | DATA | RS_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 1 | 1 | ABCABCDEFGHIJKL | 01 |
> | 0 | 5 | 5 | MNO | 05 |
> | 0 | 6 | 1 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO | 07 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=252d08ea0f293aa517770b77bea4ca4d)*